Subalgebras of a free algebra
Suppose that $V$ is a non-trivial variety, and $A$ is a one-generated algebra in $V$ which is a subalgebra of a free algebra with $n$ generators. Is $A$ isomorphic to a subalgebra of the free algebra on one generator? This problem arose when investigating the existence of a closure algebra with infinitary unification.

The answer is "not necessarily."
Consider the variety of nilpotent groups of class at most $2$ whose derived subgroup has exponent $3$; i.e., the variety of groups determined by the identities $[x,y]^3$ and $[[x,y],z]$. The relatively free group of rank $1$ is infinite cyclic, so its subgroups are either trivial or infinite cyclic. But the relatively free groups of rank $n\gt 1$ contain cyclic subgroups of order $3$; they are of course not isomorphic to subgroups of the rank $1$ relatively free group. You can construct many other examples like this.

This is a clear example and answers the general question. Is there an example for a locally finite variety of closure algebras?

@Ohbi Sorry, not familiar enough with them to answer that off the top of my head.
